# Android Time Zone Issue

Tags: android, datetime, timezone

I am using `TimeZone` class to get the time zone in `SHORT` format like `"PST", "EST"` etc. using `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT, Locale.getDefault())`

For some devices this piece of code is returning `"PST"` etc but some of the devices its returning `"GMT+007"` value. Anybody has an idea what can be the change I make to make it consistent to `"PST"` format.

Comment: Not every timezone has a 3 letter abbreviation-  especially when you force DST to off. which can cause it to be an hour off (calling a timezone PST with daylight savings off is wrong, so it won't do it).  The documentiation itself says that " Requests for this style may yield GMT offsets like GMT-08:00. "

Comment: Correct GabeSechan. Is there any way out I can make it consistent. My requirement is to get the time in these formats

HAST("US/Hawaii", "UTC-10:00"),  PST("US/Pacific", "UTC-08:00").

So if I able to get the SHORT form that is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

The short name is a part of the time zone database. It seems that some devices are shipping time zone databases that doesn't include this information, or whose libraries ignore it.

To make this consistent I would include a mapping that maps from the long names to the short names. But then you would have to maintain that yourself, and you also need to get the long name (like "US/Hawaii") for each timezone, I don't know if that is possible for you, it depends on the use case.

Please also be aware that the short time zone names are ambiguous, there are many time zones called EST for example.